# Running an iOS app in the background if you aren't publishing to the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to make my iOS app run indefinitely in the background and I'm not going to be submitting it to the app store.

Right now, I don't have an actual device to test this out and background apps seem to run forever in my Simulator.

I know that for an iOS app to run in the background it needs to satisfy certain things and Apple checks these when you submit an app to the App Store. I have gone to `project properties` > `Capabilities` > `Background modes` and ticked 'Audio and Airplay'. In reality, my app does not play any audio (not even a silent file).

Will just ticking this option allow my app to run in the background indefinitely or will I actually have to play a silent audio file to keep it running forever. Note again that I'm not submitting this app to the app store.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better using the background mode of "Voice over IP" as that will cause an app to be re-opened on restart of the device or if it is terminated by the OS.

It should just be a case of adding the entry in the plist.

As per the Apple docs:

> Because VoIP applications need to stay running in order to receive
>   incoming calls, the system automatically relaunches the application if
>   it exits with a nonzero exit code. (This could happen in cases where
>   there is memory pressure and your application is terminated as a
>   result.) However, terminating the application also releases all of its
>   sockets, including the one used to maintain the VoIP service
>   connection. Therefore, when the application is launched, it always
>   needs to create its sockets from scratch.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html

Comment: Thanks. So your answer acknowledges that iOS doesn't actually check if apps carry out the background functions that they say they do?

Comment: iOS apps don't as far as I've seen, it's down to the reviewers to check.

Comment: Going through the link you posted, I think iOS does follow through to see if the apps do what they say they do: `As long as it is playing audio or video content or recording audio content, the app continues to run in the background. However, if recording or playback stops, the system suspends the app. ` So, I think I'm going to have to code a silent audio player.

Comment: That's why you should try VoIP first. You _may_ need a socket open but give it a shot. It will only take a few seconds to test. VoIP has greater privileges than music hence the ability to relaunch.

Comment: @My app doesn't need to be rerun after a reboot. I have a question: if I go the VoIP way, will the app be able to perform all of its functions in the background (a simple get to a web service every second is what my app does) or will it be limited to functions related to the socket?

Comment: Again, I would think so. It's a 1 minute change to find out the answers so I'd really recommend just trying it.